# What's the counterpart of AFJSONRequestSerializer in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I need to serialize a Request with some default headers and an authentication token. With AFNetworking, I would create a subclass of `AFJSONRequestSerializer`. What can I do in Alamofire? I've read about response serializers but not request serializers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `alamofire` you just need to specify the headers you need before creating the request.
Something like this should work:

```
var authenticatedHeaders = ["Authorization": token, "otherHeader": otherHeader]
let request = Manager.sharedInstance.request(method, URLString, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers)
```

If your parameters need to be encoded as `JSON`, you just need to specify the encoding to `.JSON`(the default value is `.URL`).

If your request is supposed to return a `JSON` you can then trigger it using:

```
request.responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
   // parsing the response here
}
```

If you need help to parse the response, you can take a look at my alamofire fork, where I implemented a wrapper for the networking framework so that it can be used in Objective-C [Alamofire Objective-c wrapper GitHub](https://github.com/catalinaturlea/Alamofire) and this  [complete walkthrough the changes](https://medium.com/@catalinaturlea/using-alamofire-from-objective-c-18dd795e12d9#.z3unh1r8i).

Let me know if you need more information or help with this.